# Why my json-server can't find the images?

Tags: angular, json-server

I use json-server for my Angular app. I created 4 images in the specified directory but I get this error message:

```
GET /images/plan1.png 404 1.579 ms - 2
GET /images/plan2.png 404 1.950 ms - 2
GET /images/plan3.png 404 2.078 ms - 2
GET /images/plan4.png 404 2.347 ms - 2
```

Why this happens when the images are existing? I also noticed that the images aren't accessible from `localhost:3000/` through my browser too! Why?

I had 4 other images there before, and they were working well.

Answer (score 2):

I had been using my json-server on one computer and then had to move my project to a different computer and had to set up my json-server all over again. I was getting the same error I think. Finally, I realized, when setting up my json-server again, I hadn't put my "images" folder in the "public" folder. Once I did that, everything worked. I don't know if this is the same issue as yours but thought I'd share in case.

Answer (score 1):

Did you provide path to static files?

https://github.com/typicode/json-server#api

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const app = jsonServer.create();
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults({static: 'your-path'});

app.use(middlewares);
```

But since you told that it worked before with different images I assume you had to set that...it stops working just after you replace images?

Comment: Yes. After I changed the image files names in `db.json` and inside my application, it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is the files of project.

Comment: github.com/rajishpajish/test

Comment: @user3486308 ok so you're running json-server by command instead of executing file? If command can you provide it?

Comment: json-server --watch db.json

Comment: I can see other images in `localhost:3000/images/` path on my browser but the images I have added (plan1 , ... plan4` are not accessble

Comment: @user3486308 just downloaded your repo, added some new images and it works without any changes...is there a chance that maybe your request or some paths are wrong?